# dont understand the error "Uncaught TypeError:"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to print out a value off true within my objects but for some reason i keep getting this error message.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'toDoIsRemoved' of undefined  
  at removeTask (main.js:85)  
  at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:56)
```

It says that there is something wrong with line 56:

```
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{removeTask(allTheToDos[i])});
```

here is that whole function:

```
function generateHtml (){
    // Creating an Ul for my items
    let section = document.getElementById('mySection');
    let myUl = document.createElement('ul');
    myUl.className = 'listContainer';
    section.appendChild(myUl);

    // Creating the loop for my premade todo objects
    for(i=0; i<allTheToDos.length; i++){
        // Create a div wrapper for my li
        let myListWrapperItemContainer = document.createElement('div');
        myListWrapperItemContainer.className = 'listItemsWrapper';
        // Creating Checked button
        let checkedIcon = document.createElement('label');
        checkedIcon.className = 'checkedIcon listItemsIcon';
        checkedIcon.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
        //Creating li
        let myLi = document.createElement('li');
        myLi.classList = 'listItem lineTrough';
        myLi.id= 'listItem';
        // Creating delete button
        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        deleteButton.id ='deleteButton';
        deleteButton.className = 'trashCan listItemsIcon';
        deleteButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>';
        // OnClick
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{removeTask(allTheToDos[i])});

        // Adding everything to my html
        myListWrapperItemContainer.appendChild(checkedIcon);
        myListWrapperItemContainer.appendChild(myLi);
        myListWrapperItemContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
        myLi.innerHTML = allTheToDos[i].toDoItem;
        myUl.appendChild(myListWrapperItemContainer);
    }
}
```

and:

```
function removeTask (done){
    done.toDoIsRemoved = true;
    console.log(allTheToDos);
}
```

i want to be able to click on any button off my todos and be able to change the value from false to true.

Comment: One thing you should fix is that all "id" attributes on a page need to be *unique*. Your code uses the same "id" for all the buttons you add.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Please post the complete error message in your question, not in an off-site image. "something wrong with line 56" is not an error message we can help with.

Comment: Thye are supposed to be the same so that i can get access to them if i want to. and cause all off them do the same thing.

Comment: main.js:85 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'toDoIsRemoved' of undefined
    at removeTask (main.js:85)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:56)

Comment: Long story short: By the time you click the button, your loop has finished and `i` will be one above the last index of `allTheToDos`. (And since that index doesn't exist, it will return `undefined`.)

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: @MarvStarv That is all explained in the link in my first comment. That being said, don't ignore the `id` issue. Having multiple elements in your HTML with the same `id` is invalid and can cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't define `i` using `let`. Meaning you are using the **global** variable `i`. `i` will be `allTheToDos.length` after iterating. When you then later click on the event handler it will use this index, of which the value is `undefined`.

Here is the problem in short:

```js
const letters = ["a", "b", "c"];

// GLOBAL i
for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.append(letters[i]);
  button.setAttribute("type", "button");
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // The line below is not called within the loop, but when
    // you click the button. This happens after the loop is
    // finished, which is when i no longer matches
    // i < letters.length
    console.log(i, letters[i]);
  });
  document.body.append(button);
}
```

The solution is to define `i` using `let` (don't use `var` or you will have the same problem). Using `let` will scope `i` to the block, so each for-iteration has its own `i` variable, which only changes if you change it within the same block.

```js
const letters = ["a", "b", "c"];

// define i using let, scoping it to the for-block
for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.append(letters[i]);
  button.setAttribute("type", "button");
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(i, letters[i]);
  });
  document.body.append(button);
}
```

Comment: thanks for all your help, unfortunately it didn't solve the issue

Comment: @MarvStarv Could you `console.log(i, allTheToDos)` before calling `removeTask(allTheToDos[i])` **within** the *click* callback? Does it output what you expect?